# How to pass bookinstance.id for a particular book to function-based view in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django library application, wherein the customer can view a book from a book list (and is redirected to book_detail.html page), and if the book is available, can borrow the book.

**book_detail.html - borrow book button**

```
 {% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
    {% if copy.status == 'a' %}
      # <form method="POST" action ="{% url 'borrow_book' book_instance.id%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <form method="POST" action ="{% url 'borrow_book' copy.id%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Borrow the book</button>
       </form>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

**This is the urls.py routing within the app project**

```
 path('book/<uuid:pk>/borrow/', views.borrow_book, name='borrow_book'),
```

And the function borrow_book is invoked:

```
def borrow_book(request, pk):
   book_instance = get_object_or_404(BookInstance, pk=pk)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            book_instance.borrower = request.user
            book_instance.due_back = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
            book_instance.status = STATUS_ON_LOAN
            book_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_customer'))

    context = {
       'book_instance': book_instance,
    }

return render(request, 'catalog/book_detail.html', context)
```

When user clicks on Borrow book button, I need to create an instance of the book hence I am using the book_instance model.

Here is the relation between the Book and BookInstance model:

```
   class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

   class BookInstance(models.Model):
      id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
      book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
      due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
      borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

      STATUS_MAINTENANCE = 'm'
      STATUS_ON_LOAN = 'o'
      STATUS_AVAILABLE = 'a'
      STATUS_RESERVED = 'r'

     LOAN_STATUS = (
    (STATUS_MAINTENANCE, 'Maintenance'),
    (STATUS_ON_LOAN, 'On loan'),
    (STATUS_AVAILABLE, 'Available'),
    (STATUS_RESERVED, 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
     max_length=1,
     choices=LOAN_STATUS,
     blank=True,
     default='m',
     help_text='Book availability',
  )
```

On clicking the borrow_button I encounter the error:

```
   NoReverseMatch at /catalog/book/16

   Reverse for 'borrow_book' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/book/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/borrow/$']

    Request Method: GET
```

So, in book-detail.html, how do I pass(in which manner) the book_instance.id to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
action ="{% url 'borrow_book' copy.id%}"
```

`copy` seems to be a single instance of your iteration.

```
{% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Here is the solution:

```
   <form method="POST" action ="{% url 'borrow_book' copy.id%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">. 
   # use copy.id to get instance of that book
```